# ¿Cómo puedo devolver el string más largo en javascript?

Tags: javascript

La función llamada 'stringMasLarga', recibe como argumento un arreglo de strings llamado 'strings' y debe devolver el string más largo que hay en el arreglo (Es decir el de mayor cantidad de caracteres). Por ejemplo:

```js
stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']); // debe retornar 'guten tag'
stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']); // debe retornar 'JavaScript'
```

Mi intento fue lo siguiente:

```
var masLarga1 = [];
var masLarga2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length + 1; i++) {
  if (strings[i] === [strings[i]] + 1) {
    masLarga1 = masLarga1 + [strings[i]] + 1;
  }
  return 'JavaScript';
}
if (strings[i] !== [strings[i]] + 1) {
  masLarga2 = masLarga2 + [strings[i]] + 1;
}
return 'guten tag';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con un **`for`**:

```js
function stringMasLarga(array) {
  let size = 0;
  let result = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].length > size) {
      size = array[i].length;
      result = array[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']));
console.log(stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']));
```

O también, algo más sencillo sería utilizando **`reduce()`**:

```js
function stringMasLarga(array){
  result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
  return result;
}

console.log(stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']))
console.log(stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']))
```

Comment: Gracias Cris...

Comment: Usando el .reduce() sirvió ESPECTACULAR... Gracias de nuevo, Cris

Answer (score 2):

```
//Te podria quedar algo asi**

let size = 0;
let stringLarga = null;
for (const x of strings) {
    if (size < x.length) {
        size = x.length;
        stringLarga = x;
    }
}
return stringLarga;
```

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré.

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo tu razonamiento podrías hacer algo así:

```js
function stringMasLarga(strList) {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < strList.length - 1; i++) {
    if (strList[i + 1].length > strList[i].length) {
      result = strList[i + 1];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(stringMasLarga(["hi", "hello", "ni hao", "guten tag"]));
```

Lo que hace esta función lo siguiente:

1. Recibir por parámetro el array de strings
2. Genera una variable auxiliar para guardar la palabra más larga
   encontrada.
3. Recorrer todos los strings del array (acá en la condición se agrega **length - 1** por que estamos comparando un string con el siguiente, entonces    debemos cortar en un indice anterior al último, porque si llegamos al último estaríamos comparando con algo que no está definido, y eso nos daría error al intentar obtener el length de undefined).
4. Comparamos si el largo del string siguiente es mayor al que estamos    recorriendo.
5. Si se cumplió lo anterior volcamos el valor del    string más largo en result y esto se vuelve a repetir, si se    encuentra otro más largo reemplazará al valor en result, sino quedará    el primero agregado.
6. Finalmente retornamos result donde tenemos    guardada nuestro string más largo.

---

Si tuviera que hacerlo de cero quizás optaría más por algo como:

```js
function stringMasLarga(strList) {
  let largeStr = "";
  for (const str of strList) {
    if (str.length > largeStr.length) largeStr = str;
  }
  return largeStr;
}

console.log(stringMasLarga(["hi", "hello", "ni hao", "guten tag"]));
```

Aquí lo que se hace es definir una variable auxiliar que inicia siendo un string vacío por lo que su length es 0.
Luego se recorre cada string y se compara el length de la palabra recorrida con el length de largeStr, si es mayor guarda esa palabra en largeStr, por lo que el length de este pasa a ser el largo de esa palabra más larga.
Finalmente se retorna la palabra guardada en largeStr.

Comment: Gracias Luis...

Answer (score 0):

Otra más (aunque todas se parecen), esta vez con [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) donde recorremos los valores de los array y los vamos comparando con el anterior, guardándolo solo si el que se evalua en el ciclo es más largo que el anterior:

```js
function stringMasLarga(array) {
  cadenaLarga = '';
  array.forEach(x => {
    if (cadenaLarga.length < x.length) {
      cadenaLarga = x
    }
  })
  console.log(cadenaLarga)
}

stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']); // debe retornar 'guten tag'
stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']); // debe retornar 'JavaScript'
```