# Encontrar la plabara mas larga de un array en Javascript

Tags: javascript

alguno me puede colaborar con esta duda porfavor.
Me estan pidiendo lo siguiente:

La funcion llamada 'palabraMasLarga' recibe un array 'array' de frases (strings) como parametro
y debe devolver la palabra mas larga entre todas las frases ( Es decir la palabra con mayor cantidad de caracteres)
Por ej:
palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']) debe devolver 'palabra'

Intente hacerlo de esta forma :

```
     `function palabraMasLarga(array) {

   var strSplit = array.split(" ", ",", "'");  
  var largoPalabra = 0; 
  var palabra = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) { 

    if (largoPalabra < strSplit[i].length) { 
      palabra = strSplit[i]
      largoPalabra = strSplit[i].length;  
      
    }
    return (palabra)
  }
} `
```

pero me muestra el siguiente error : TypeError: array.split is not a function

La pregunta mia es, ¿que otra forma hay para yo recorrer palabra por palabra el array? Pasa que si digamos comparo : array[0] este lo que va a hacer es mostrarme todo el texto (hola esto string) no la pabra (hola), y no se como mas podria recorrer el array :(

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/571503/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-devolver-el-string-m%c3%a1s-largo-en-javascript/571523#571523

Comment: Lo estás haciendo al revés. 1) Tienes un array --> lo reccores con un `for`, 2) Cada item del for es una frase -> haces un split, que te da un nuevo array  3) Vuelves a hacer un for a ese nuevo array. Y siempre evaluando si la nueva palabra es más grande que la que tienes guardada

Comment: En el primero estan comparando elementos de un array, pero estan de a 1, ese ejercicio yo lo resolvi, pero en este me piden que busque la palabra mas larga de una frase en un array, y en el array son varias frase (separadas cada una como si fuera distinta indice del array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dejo la explicación en los comentarios

```js
function palabraMasLarga(array) {
   var palabra = "";
  //1) Recorremos el array
  
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     //2) cada item es una frase, asi que hacemos un split
     var palabraS = array[i].split(" ");
     
     //3) Iteramos sobre este nuevo array, para recorrer cada palabra
     for(var j=0; j<palabraS.length; j++){
        //4) Evaluamos si esta palabra es más larga que la que tenemos guardad
        
        if(palabraS[j].length>palabra.length){
           //guardamos la mas larga
           palabra = palabraS[j];
        }
     }
     
  }
  
  return palabra;
} 

var respuesta =palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']) ;

console.log(respuesta);
```